# manage 2 git users gpg key and choose gpg sign per user

Tags: git, gpg-signature

I have 1 github user and another gitlab user, and I have created 1 gpg key for each because my email address differs.

The problem is I have to execute `git config --global user.signingkey` everytime I want to commit to different git repos.

Is there a way I can manage my gpg keys per git user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify Git identity based on SSH host or identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291450/specify-git-identity-based-on-ssh-host-or-identity)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have the same situation but with splitting of work/personal accounts. And I have a lot of repositories but I don't want to run `git config` every time I clone something new.

I have written [a blog post](https://dev.to/chakrit/multiple-identity-gitconfig-with-gpg-signing-8c0) about it. A way to do this automatically is to use the `includeIf` directive provided by git. You can read more about it from the [Conditional Include](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes) section in git manual.

---

There's a small requirement tho, **you need to be able to tell apart github repositories from your GitLab repositories by a component in your path** (for example, put GitHub clones in `~/github` and Gitlab clones in `~/gitlab`)

Then, basically, split the signing key configuration into two files:

```ini
# config.github
[user]
  name       = Chakrit
  email      = github@example.com
  signingkey = DEADBEEF

# config.gitlab
[user]
  name       = Chakrit
  email      = gitlab@example.com
  signingkey = BADC0FFEE
```

And then in your main `~/.config/git/config` configuration file, use the `includeIf gitdir:` directive to match and include different files based on your WD:

```ini
# when working with github
[includeIf "gitdir:**/github/**/.git"]
  path = config.github

# when working with gitlab
[includeIf "gitdir:**/gitlab/**/.git"]
  path = config.gitlab
```

Then all repos in your `~/github` folder will automatically use your GitHub key and repos in your `~/gitlab` folder will use your GitLab keys.

Comment: Would the .gitconfig also use relative path ?

Comment: Where is the "signing key configuration" file ? I suppose it is not the same as ~/.config/git/config ?

Comment: In the example given, create the files `config.github` and `config.gitlab` in the same directory as the main config file. Each github/gitlab config should contain the different user key info.

Comment: Yes, what Haren said.

Comment: Everyone, please note that this answer relates to a *much more* specific problem. The OP doesn't want to run `git config --global` after **switching their context** between multiple repositories. The answer author doesn't want to run `git config` after each time they **clone** a new repository.

Answer (score 5):

The signingkey may be set per-repository, just execute: `git config user.signingkey` from within a checked out repository. This command sets the configuration in the repositor's `.git/config`. The `--global` options causes the config to be written into `~/.gitconfig` where it becomes the default for repositories that do not have a local value set.

More information can be found in `git-config`'s man page in the user.signingKey section.

You may also get better results by also setting `user.email` to the email associated with the repository.

Comment: This should be much higher. The question doesn't acknowledge that this can be per-repo and seems to assume they have to change the global setting each time.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove all `user.signingkey` settings from your repo and your global settings.

`git` will decide to use a key in`gpg` with a matching identity for the `user.email` setting from your repo.

Comment: Can you share the official documentations which states this in a more elaborate manner?

Comment: @Jarmos: [user.signingKey](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-usersigningKey): "If git-tag or git-commit is not selecting the key you want it to automatically when creating a signed tag or commit, you can override the default selection with this variable. [...]"

[gpg.ssh.defaultKeyCommand](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-gpgsshdefaultKeyCommand): "This command that will be run when user.signingkey is not set and a ssh signature is requested. [...]"

Comment: That won't work if your login account UPN is not the same as the email used for signing key.

Answer (score 1):

I'd improve @chakrit's answer, but the edit queue is full since a while...

I prefer a file-system-agnostic approach and load the correct configuration based on the remote Git host URL:

```ini
[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:**/github.com*/**"]
    path = config.github
```